# Avoid to save an instance in a pre_save Signal without using raise Exception

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-signals

I have **two models**. When I save an instance from the first I need to send a field value from this Model into the other one's field.

First Model:

```
class ModelOne(models.Model):
    # fields...
    quantity = models.FloatField()
```

Second Model:

```
class ModelTwo(models.Model):
    # fields...
    quantity = models.FloatField()
```

pre_save signal:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=ModelOne)
def verify(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # Stuff
    quantity = instance.quantity
    founded_model_two = ModelTwo.objects.get("""Something""")
    future_result = founded_model_two.quantity - quantity
    if future_result < 0:
        raise Exception("Cannot be less than zero")
```

I want to avoid to save the instance, but I don't want to raise an Exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to look out for Exception in `pre_save`, you could do it in `save` method. Because ideally `pre_save` should be throwing Exception to stop the signal to finish.

```
class ModelOne(models.Model):
    # fields...
    quantity = models.FloatField()


    def save(self):
        if some_condition:
            super(ModelOne, self).save()
        else:
           return   #cancel the save if you return no super save object.
```

IMHO, you don't need to do all that and can use `Validators` for checking whether you data needs to be saved. If you have a `form` saving the data, then use the form validation to stop saving the data.